# Throwing exception while am using the statements

Tags: asp.net

> int value = dropdownlist1.selectedIndex;

(index '0' is selected and it does not have any number)

so, `value = 0;`

i want to check, `if(value == 0)`,

if yes, i need to display as `value ="";`

else
`int value = dropdownlist1.selectedItem.value;`

Comment: What do you mean by "i need to display as value=""; " ..?

Comment: if(value == 0) value ="";

Comment: what's the exception?

Comment: int value = int.parse(dropdownlist1.selectedvalue) This statement throwing exception, because i didnt select any value from the dropdown, its in 0th index.

Answer (score 4):

try to compare in if statement instead of taking value into variable.

```
if (dropdownlist1.SelectedIndex == 0)
{

}
else { }
```

Comment: Shall i use this code as if(dropdownlist1.selectedIndex == 0) then value =""; else dropdownlist1.selectedIndex

Comment: Yes ... and you can take selectedValue as well.... that will be the value that you gave to your dropdownitem